# How do I convert a pandas dataframe to a 1d array?

Tags: visualization, pandas

I'm trying to create a contour map from two variables which store some temperature values and a third variable which is the time stamp.
I used this notebook as a tutorial

> https://plot.ly/pandas/contour-plots/

I'm not able to convert the pandas dataframe created, into a 1d array. And the kde_scipy doesn't work with a nd-array. I tried converting the dataframe into a 1d array using .as_matrix() but this is the error I am receiving.

```
Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
```

How can I convert this CSV file (with 3 columns of data) imported as a dataframe into individual columns of data? Or can I directly import each column of data into a 1d array and use it in the function kde_scipy?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
filename = 'data.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(filename)
#convert dataframe to matrix
conv_arr= df1.values

#split matrix into 3 columns each into 1d array

arr1 = np.delete(conv_arr,[1,2],axis=1) 
arr2 = np.delete(conv_arr,[0,2],axis=1) 
arr3 = np.delete(conv_arr,[0,1],axis=1) 

#converting into 1D array
arr1 = arr1.ravel()
arr2 = arr2.ravel()
arr3 = arr3.ravel()
```

This should mostly do the job. Use the arr1 ,arr2,arr3 in the function you mentioned. They are the 1d array of the columns you split

Answer (score 5):

You can first convert the `DataFrame` to NumPy format by calling [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), after which the resulting `numpy.ndarray` has the same dimensions as your original `DataFrame`. Then, run [`.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) to collapse it into one dimension.

```py
my_dataframe.values.flatten()
```

Comment: `.flatten()` returns a copy, `.ravel()` a view.